# How to generate JMeter dashboard report on Linux system with huge jtl file and having different file system with limited disk space

Tags: linux, jmeter

I have a huge jtl file `~31GB` in size. This jtl file is in location `/opt`.

Following is the result of two linux commands:

```
[opt]$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_root   50G  3.0G   44G   7% /
/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_opt    50G   31G   17G  65% /opt

[opt]$ ls -ltrh
total 30G
-rw-rw-r--   1 - -  30G Oct 24 13:04 Run.jtl
-rw-------   1 - - 638K Nov  4 10:48 nohup.out
```

As you can see my `Run.jtl` file is in `/opt` which is in `/dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_opt filesystem [only has 17GB disk space left]`. When I run Jmeter command to generate dashboard,jmeter creates temp file and it run out of space.

```
jmeter -g Run.jtl -o ~/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/Run/
```

> Here, ~/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/Run/ is in /dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_root
>   filesystem, but nothing happens there and I ran out of disk space in
>   /dev/mapper/vg_os-lv_opt filesystem because of Run.jtl and temp file
>   :(

Any suggestion on how I can generate the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) which can be used for setting the intermediate temporary files location for the report generation, you can define it via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir=/tmp -g /path/to/your/.jtl file -o /tmp/dashboard
```

just make sure to have this `jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir` and the location of the dashboard outside of the `/opt` folder.

To make the change permanent add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir=/tmp
```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for highlighting this feature.